# Why is my alarm being set recursively?

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-alarms

I have two values in my Database:

Hour = 10

Minute = 20

#### EDIT:

By Recursive I dont mean that the alarm is being set for tomorrow and hence forth, the onReceive of my Alarm class is getting called recursively.

I have the following function to set and Alarm using the above values from Database.

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context){

        
        retrieve(context); // returns the hour, minute and day value. 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        
        Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarNow.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); //Now calendar
        
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(timeOneHour));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.valueOf(timeOneMinute) ); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


        
        if(calendar.after(calendarNow)){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        }else{
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));
        }
        
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationsEngine.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, pi); 
        
        
        
        
    }
```

What I simply want is to set an alarm for today if the time (10:20 - this can be changed by the user but right now I am finding problems with this time in particular) has not passed - else set the alarm for tomorrow at the same time.

I first register this alarm in the Mainactivity - which is the start of my application ( I do check if the alarm is already set or not - so that I dont repeat. Then I register the alarm once again after executing my code in service which is invoked by this alarm.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
        context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));

    }
```

in the Service(After I execute the code which I intend to be executed by this alarm:

```
notifEngine.SetAlarm(getApplicationContext());
```

This issue was not happening till 2014. I presume change in year has triggered something bad!

#### Edit:

On debugging the following lines seem to be the culprit:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));
            System.out.println("On Day"+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

The System.out prints 2 to the console, which ideally should print 3 - I might be wrong here but I think something is wrong here.

So I think I have zeroed down on the issue:

```
System.out.println("On Day before adding: "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));
            System.out.println("On Day after adding: "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Both the above print commands give an output of 2.

Comment: `am.setRepeating()` sets a **repeating** alarm. `am.set()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: am.setRepeating() because I want the alarm to repeat tomorrow? Also I am clueless as in why this did not prop up before when it was 2014. Makes me doubt the above function.

Comment: No. The correct way (if the alarm is for today and tomorrow only) is to `set()` it once for today. Then `set()` it again, shifted by 1 day (with controls on the dates, not to re-set it indefinetely). `setRepeating()` will fire forever.

Comment: Actually I want the alarm to trigger everyday, not just today and tomorrow. But I think your idea carries weight and let me right away try that. Because anyway after I finish my servece class I can call to set the alarm again.

Comment: `Actually I want the alarm to trigger everyday, not just today and tomorrow` seems to conflict with `Why is my alarm being set recursively?`. Maybe I didn't get the question sense.

Comment: Recursively that as soon as I opened my app in 2015 All I could see is the calls to set alarm - the function I produced is getting called each millisecond. I first set alarm in my MainActivity, then I set it again once the service executed by this alarm is finished. This cycle is repeating. That is why I suspected the function and not the setRepeating.

Comment: I tried the suggestion of using alarm.set instead of setRepeating, does not solve the issue. There is a problem in calendar I think, somehow its triggering the onRecieved.

Comment: `as soon as I opened my app in 2015` - Well, maybe you forgot to change the **YEAR**? So, the alarm was set to fire in 2014, which is **past**, so it will fire **immediately**.

Comment: From the Docs: Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and time Darn this is a production app and I think I am screwed!

Comment: This is why a date saved in 2014 retains the 2014 year. You only change the day of month: `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1`. So if it was 2014-12-31, you'll get 2014-01-01 (31+1). Which is **past**

Comment: But this calendar is not static, @DerGolem bro, I think there is something still eluding here- the system.out.println commands should not print 2 in both. Did you check my update?

Comment: What if you change `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));` to `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1));` (moving the **+ 1** outside the get instruction)?

Comment: Works mate, I had posted this in another thread as well, and that is where my problem lies! Now quickly construct an answer out of your comments so that I can accept it!