# Why does not the Day change after adding 1 to the calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

I have the following code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(timeOneHour));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.valueOf(timeOneMinute) ); 
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
```

Where timeOneHour = 10
and timeOneMinute = 20

Now I do the following:

```
System.out.println("On Day before adding: "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));
System.out.println("On Day after adding: "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Both of the above println commands are printing out 2 - what is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: I think you need `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1` (note the closing parenthesis)

Comment: `(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)` is in parenthesis. I also think you are correct but logic eludes me in this case!

Comment: `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is a constant. You don't want to add 1 to the constant but to the return value of `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`.

Comment: There is only one more doubt here - this issue did not happen from August of 2014 till the new year that is 31 Dec 2014. Why?

Comment: `This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."` [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740222/why-is-my-alarm-being-set-recursively) is the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try incrementing the day like so : ?

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: While as your answer does give me perfect solution but I would also want to know,How is `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));` different from the same?

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of `add()/set()` methods:[doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#GregorianCalendar.add%28int%2Cint%29). Using the add() method will complete your task, like I answered above. Problem is that DAY_OF_MONTH is an enum and you are just increasing the enum value. It will work when you take the +1 out of the paranthesis as the others stated above, but using  the add method is better.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error where +1 is added

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1)));
```

should be

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1));
```

You are acutally adding one to the constant, DAY_OF_MONTH, which happens to be DAY_OF_YEAR. For january they are the same.)

Comment: Thank you, it does solve my issue. Need to read up a bit more on constants.